# Pass cython functions via python interface

Tags: python, scipy, cython

Can a `cdef` Cython function be passed to another (python `def`) cython function from a Python script?

Minimal example:

**test_module.pyx**

```
cpdef min_arg(f, int N):
    cdef double x = 100000.
    cdef int best_i = -1

    for i in range(N):
        if f(i) < x:
            x = f(i)
            best_i = i
    return best_i

def py_f(x):
    return (x-5)**2

cdef public api double cy_f(double x):
    return (x-5)**2
```

**test.py**

```
import pyximport; pyximport.install()
import testmodule

testmodule.min_arg(testmodule.py_f, 100)
```

This works well, but I want to be able to also do

```
testmodule.min_arg(testmodule.cy_f, 100)
```

from a test.py, to have cython's speed (no Python overhead for each `f(i)` call). But obviously, Python doesn't know about cy_f, because it's not `def` or `cpdef` declared.

I was hoping something like this existed:

```
from scipy import LowLevelCallable
cy_f = LowLevelCallable.from_cython(testmodule, 'cy_f')
testmodule.min_arg(cy_f, 100)
```

But this gives `TypeError: 'LowLevelCallable' object is not callable`.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LowLevelCallable` is a class of functions that must be accepted by the underlying Python module. This work has been done for a few modules, including the quadrature routine [scipy.integrate.quad](http://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html#scipy.integrate.quad)

If you wish to use the same wrapping method, you must either go through the SciPy routines that make use of it, such as `scipy.ndimage.generic_filter1d` or `scipy.integrate.quad`. The code sits in compiled extensions, however.

The alternative, if your problem is reasonably well defined for the callback, is to implement this yourself. I have done this in one of my codes, so I post the link for simplicity:

1. In a `.pxd` file, I define the interface `cyfunc_d_d`: https://github.com/pdebuyl/skl1/blob/master/skl1/core.pxd
2. I can re-use this interface in the "base" cython module https://github.com/pdebuyl/skl1/blob/master/skl1/euler.pyx and also in a "user-defined" module.

The final code makes plain "cython-cython" calls while allowing the passing of objects at the Cython level

I adapted the code to your problem:

1. `test_interface.pxd`

   ```
   cdef class cyfunc:                                                                                                                         
       cpdef double f(self, double x)                                                                                                         

   cdef class pyfunc(cyfunc):                                                                                                                 
       cdef object py_f                                                                                                                       
       cpdef double f(self, double x)
   ```
2. `test_interface.pyx`

   ```
   cdef class cyfunc:
       cpdef double f(self, double x):
           return 0
       def __cinit__(self):
           pass


   cdef class pyfunc(cyfunc):
       cpdef double f(self, double x):
           return self.py_f(x)
       def __init__(self, f):
           self.py_f = f
   ```
3. `setup.py`

   ```
   from setuptools import setup, Extension                                                                                                    
   from Cython.Build import cythonize                                                                                                         

   setup(                                                                                                                                     
       ext_modules=cythonize((Extension('test_interface', ["test_interface.pyx"]),                                                            
                             Extension('test_module', ["test_module.pyx"]))                                                                   
                         )                                                                                                                    
   )
   ```
4. `test_module.pyx`

   ```
   from test_interface cimport cyfunc, pyfunc                                                                                                 

   cpdef min_arg(f, int N):                                                                                                                   
       cdef double x = 100000.                                                                                                                
       cdef int best_i = -1                                                                                                                   
       cdef int i                                                                                                                             
       cdef double current_value                                                                                                              

       cdef cyfunc py_f                                                                                                                       

       if isinstance(f, cyfunc):                                                                                                              
           py_f = f                                                                                                                           
           print('cyfunc')                                                                                                                    
       elif callable(f):                                                                                                                      
           py_f = pyfunc(f)                                                                                                                   
           print('no cyfunc')                                                                                                                 
       else:                                                                                                                                  
           raise ValueError("f should be a callable or a cyfunc")                                                                             

       for i in range(N):                                                                                                                     
           current_value = py_f.f(i)                                                                                                          
           if current_value < x:                                                                                                              
               x = current_value                                                                                                              
               best_i = i                                                                                                                     
       return best_i                                                                                                                          

   def py_f(x):                                                                                                                               
       return (x-5)**2                                                                                                                        

   cdef class cy_f(cyfunc):                                                                                                                   
       cpdef double f(self, double x):                                                                                                        
           return (x-5)**2
   ```

To use:

```
python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace
python3 -c 'import test_module ; print(test_module.min_arg(test_module.cy_f(), 10))'
python3 -c 'import test_module ; print(test_module.min_arg(test_module.py_f, 10))'
```