# Pass c function as argument to python function in cython

Tags: cython

I have the following code which works:

```
%%cython 

cdef int add(int  a, int b):
    return a+b

cdef int mult(int  a, int b):
    return a*b

ctypedef int (*function_type)(int  a, int b)

cdef int lambda_c(function_type func, int c, int d):
    return func(c,d)

print(lambda_c(add, 5, 6))
print(lambda_c(mult, 5, 6))
```

So I have `lambda_c` function that takes c function as an argument and I am not able to change it (as it it a wrapper over c library that is supported by another team).

What I want to do is to write a wrapper:

```
cdef class PyClass:
    def py_wrap(func, e, f):
        return lambda_c(func, e, f)

print(PyClass().py_wrap(add, 5, 5))
print(PyClass().py_wrap(mult, 6, 6))
```

But this throws an error:

> Cannot convert Python object to 'function_type'

I also tried to cast func(`return lambda_c(<function_type>func, e, f)`) but got an error:

> Python objects cannot be cast to pointers of primitive types

**The idea** behind this is following: any user will be able to write his own function in cython, compile it and then import and pass his function to `PyClass().py_wrap` method.

Is it even possible to import pure c function and pass it as a parameter with cython?

I also saw [Pass cython functions via python interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46038154/pass-cython-functions-via-python-interface) but unlike the solution there I am not able to change `lambda_c` functon and turn it into a class. Moreover `lambda_c` takes only functions of certain type (`function_type` in our example)

Comment: You cannot pass a pointer as argument to a def-function, only to cdef.

Comment: @ead is it passible to pass pointer into `cdef py_wrap(func, e, f)` method of class `PyClass`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to pass an arbitrary *Python* callable as a C function pointer then it doesn't work - there's no way to do this in standard C (and thus it's impossible to for Cython to generate the code). There's a very hacky workaround involving `ctypes` (which can do runtime code generation which I'll find links to if needed. However I don't really recommend it.

If you're happy for your users to write `cdef` functions in Cython (the question implies you are) then you can just build on [my answer to your question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57462173/4657412).

1. Write a suitable wrapper class (you just need to change the function pointer type) - this gets split between *your* .pxd  and .pyx files that you write.
2. Have your users `cimport` it and then use it to expose their `cdef` classes to Python:

   ```
   from your_module cimport FuncWrapper

   cdef int add_c_implementation(int  a, int b):
       return a+b

   # `add` accessible from Python
   add = WrapperFunc.make_from_ptr(add_c_implementation)
   ```
3. Change `PyClass` to take `FuncWrapper` as an argument:

   ```
   # this is in your_module.pyx

   cdef class PyClass:
       def py_wrap(FuncWrapper func, e, f):
           return lambda_c(func.func, e, f)
   ```
4. Your users can then use their compiled functions from Python:

   ```
   from your_module import PyClass
   from users_module import add

   PyClass().py_wrap(add,e,f)
   ```

---

Really all this is doing is using a small Python wrapper to allow you to pass around a type that Python normally can't deal with. You're pretty limited in what it's possible to do with these wrapped function pointers (for example they *must* be set up in Cython) but it does give a handle to select and pass them.

Comment: Thank you very much! One more detail, as far as I understand I can compile the main package and than cimport from installed one the `FuncWrapper` and build a new one. I tried this, but get `'wrap.pxd' not found` when try to cimport wrap.  I added `packages=['wrap']` to setup function from setuptools but it didn't help

Comment: I think the main thing is for `wrap.pxd` to be on the Python path. As a proof of concept try to build your other package in the same directory as `wrap` and it should work. If you're using a different directory then the `cimport` needs to reflect that. This is always something that's a bit difficult to get right unfortunately and I don't understand best practice that well

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you are allowed to change the function pointer type from

```py
ctypedef int (*function_type)(int  a, int b)
```

to

```py
ctypedef int (*function_type)(int a, int b, void *func_d)
```

but this is usually the way callback functions are implemented in C. `void *` parameter `func_d` to the function contains the user-provided data in any form. If the answer is yes, then you can have the following solution.

First, create the following definition file in Cython to reveal your C API to other Cython users:

```py
# binary_op.pxd
ctypedef int (*func_t)(int a, int b, void *func_d) except? -1

cdef int func(int a, int b, void *func_d) except? -1

cdef class BinaryOp:
  cpdef int eval(self, int a, int b) except? -1

cdef class Add(BinaryOp):
  cpdef int eval(self, int a, int b) except? -1

cdef class Multiply(BinaryOp):
  cpdef int eval(self, int a, int b) except? -1
```

This basically allows any Cython user to `cimport` these definitions directly into their Cython code and bypass any Python-related function calls. Then, you implement the module in the following `pyx` file:

```py
# binary_op.pyx
cdef int func(int a, int b, void *func_d) except? -1:
  return (<BinaryOp>func_d).eval(a, b)

cdef class BinaryOp:
  cpdef int eval(self, int a, int b) except? -1:
    raise NotImplementedError()

cdef class Add(BinaryOp):
  cpdef int eval(self, int a, int b) except? -1:
    return a + b

cdef class Multiply(BinaryOp):
  cpdef int eval(self, int a, int b) except? -1:
    return a * b

def call_me(BinaryOp oper not None, c, d):
  return func(c, d, <void *>oper)
```

As you can see, `BinaryOp` serves as the base class which raises `NotImplementedError` for its users who do not implement `eval` properly. `cpdef` functions can be overridden by both Cython and Python users, and if they are called from Cython, efficient C calling mechanisms are involved. Otherwise, there is a small overhead when called from Python (well, of course, these functions work on scalars, and hence, the overhead *might not* be that small).

Then, a Python user might have the following application code:

```py
# app_1.py
import pyximport
pyximport.install()

from binary_op import BinaryOp, Add, Multiply, call_me

print(call_me(Add(), 5, 6))
print(call_me(Multiply(), 5, 6))

class LinearOper(BinaryOp):
  def __init__(self, p1, p2):
    self.p1 = p1
    self.p2 = p2
  def eval(self, a, b):
    return self.p1 * a + self.p2 * b

print(call_me(LinearOper(3, 4), 5, 6))
```

As you can see, they can not only create objects from efficient Cython (concrete) classes (i.e., `Add` and `Multiply`) but also implement their own classes based on `BinaryOp` (hopefully by providing the implementation to `eval`). When you run `python app_1.py`, you will see (after the compilations):

```
11
30
39
```

Then, your Cython users can implement their favorite functions as follows:

```py
# sub.pyx
from binary_op cimport BinaryOp

cdef class Sub(BinaryOp):
  cpdef int eval(self, int a, int b) except? -1:
    return a - b
```

Well, of course, any application code that uses `sub.pyx` can use both libraries as follows:

```py
import pyximport
pyximport.install()

from sub import Sub
from binary_op import call_me

print(call_me(Sub(), 5, 6))
```

When you run `python app_2.py`, you get the expected result: `-1`.

**EDIT.** By the way, provided that you are allowed to have the aforementioned `function_type` signature (i.e., the one that has a `void *` parameter as the third argument), you *can* in fact pass an arbitrary Python callable object as a C pointer. For this to happen, you need to have the following changes:

```py
# binary_op.pyx
cdef int func(int a, int b, void *func_d) except? -1:
  return (<object>func_d)(a, b)


def call_me(oper not None, c, d):
  return func(c, d, <void *>oper)
```

Note, however, that Python now needs to figure out which `object` `oper` is. In the former solution, we were constraining `oper` to be a valid `BinaryOp` object. Note also that `__call__` and similar special functions can *only* be declared `def`, which limits your use case. Nevertheless, with these last changes, we can have the following code run without any problems:

```py
print(call_me(lambda x, y: x - y, 5, 6))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @ead , I have changed code a bit and the result satisfies me:

```
cdef class PyClass:
    cdef void py_wrap(self, function_type func, e, f):
        print(lambda_c(func, e, f))

PyClass().py_wrap(mult, 5, 5)
```

For my purposes it is ok to have void function, but I do not know, how to make it all work with method, that should return some value. Any ideas for this case will be useful

**UPD:** `cdef` methods are not visible from python, so it looks like there is no way to make things work

Comment: One way that you could expose the function pointer to python would be to wrap that function pointer in a cdef class instead. Another option could be to use python's capsule api to wrap the function pointer instead. You might want to take a look at scipy's LowLevelCallable for some inspiration.