# Cython: Memoryviewslice vs C array

Tags: python, cython, memoryview

I define a C function with memoryview input to work with a NumPy array, but a pure C-defined temporary float array can not work with 'base_func'. Error:

> Operation not allowed without gil

How can I modify C function *base_func* to work with both the *numpy.array* and *cdef* C array?

```
cdef void base_func(float[:] vec1) noexcept nogil:
    return

def python_entry(vec: np.ndarray):
    cdef float[:] vec_view = vec
    base_func(vec_view)

cdef void cfunc(float[:] vec2) noexcept nogil:
    cdef float[10] tmp_vec
    base_func(tmp_vec)
```

#### Error Message

```
cdef void cfunc(float[:] vec2) noexcept nogil:
    cdef float[10] tmp_vec
    base_func(tmp_vec)              ^
------------------------------------------------------------

c_test.pyx:21:14: Operation not allowed without gil
```

---

#### Project Idea

I want to cythonize the **GROUP BY** operation on 1D or 2D np.ndarray. The python interface will be like group_mean(data, group), and group_mean = FuncWrapper(c_group_mean). So I can write other c-functions like **c_group_std** to implement another python interface **group_std**

Problems and Resolutions:

1. **Shape Alignment and NAN input**: Randomly, **data** will be shaped as (m, n) and **group** as (n, ), I have to align them and use **np.where** to assign -1 to group where data is NAN.
2. **Work on 2D array**: the c-func will only work on 1D input, so for 2D data, I use **prange** to operate on each row simultaneously, which needs **NOGIL** mode.
3. **Different Shaped Result**: For (m, n) shaped input data, output could be shaped as (m, group_number) for statistical function such as group_mean, and as (m, n) for operation function such as group_demean (subtract corresponding group mean), so I have different FuncWrapper.
4. **Python Object FuncWrapper can't use c function pointer as parameter**: create a CFuncWrapper (cdef class) to wrap c functions like c_group_mean, accordind to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57477827/pass-c-function-as-argument-to-python-function-in-cython).
5. **Initialize temporary c array and reuse c function**: For example, in c_group_mean, I need two arrays to sum up data and count in each group. So my **c function template** looks like following, which [raise error on Windows 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77475468/cython-initialize-list-with-length-const-input-raise-error-on-windows) but works on macos. And also I can't call c_mean in c_std and pass in my **temporary float array** mean as **result** parameter

```
cdef void c_mean (float[:] data, int[:] group, float[:] result, const int length, const int group_number):
   float[group_num] sum_up
   int[group_num] count
```

So my final code should be,

group_mean = FuncWrapper(CFuncWrapper.bind_cfunc_group_num(c_group_mean))

#### Further Thinking

1. Change all float[group_num] sum_up to float* sum_up = <float*>malloc(...), to work on Window 11?
2. Change **c function template** to allow both memoryviewslice and float* to pass in? Or change the architecture to,

```
1. Python Interface: group_mean
2. FuncWrapper: pass in different base function, like c_group_mean
3. CFuncWrapper: make sure python object FuncWrapper can accept cdef functions
4. TODO: convert MemoryviewSlice to float*?
5. base c functions: c_group_mean, c_group_std
```

Comment: A memoryview is ultimately a Python-derived data structure so creating it requires allocating a Python object and so needs the GIL. You can access it efficiently without, and pass memoryviews to memoryviews without, but the first time you make it you do need the GIL. Is there a *good* reason why you want everything to be `nogil`?

Comment: @DavidW The basic idea is to complement GROUPBY operation, such as group_mean or group_std, on 1D array or on 2D array row by row. I want to use prange, which needs 'nogil',  to call 1D-function in a for loop on each row in 2D array. And I want to call group_mean in group_std (both are c-func), but it failed.

Comment: @DavidW I just edited my post to make it clear. Feel free to give any comments or suggestions, and I really appreciate it. Thanks!